# How do I create a function to run a t.test over multiple columns

Tags: r, function

I am trying to run a t.test with a binomial variable and outcome variable like this

```
t.test(outcomevar~binomialvar, data=d)
```

But I want to write a function to run this for 5 columns (column 22 to 27) so I dont have to continue to write out the full code.

Im new to writing functions so im just a little confused on the syntax, this is what I tried

```
fun1<- function(x){t.test(c(22:27)==x ,binomialvar, data)%>%pvalue()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just loop over the names, create a formula with `reformulate`

```
out <- sapply(names(d)[22:27), function(nm)
       t.test(reformulate("binomialvar", response = nm), data = d)$p.value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! can I ask the function(nm) term is the nm significant there? sorry still new to all of this!

Comment: @JuliaFontana It is looping over column names 22:27, and the function(nm) is a lambda function or anonmymous function with `nm` values the corresponding column names or 22 to 27